# undefined method `belogns_to'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have some code in view:

```
<%= form_for(:report_main, :url => {:action => 'exporttoxiccreate'}) do |f| %>
<%= select_tag('vrstaotpada',options_for_select([['Komercijalni otpad', 'Komercijalni otpad'], ['Industrijski otpad', 'Industrijski otpad']])) %>
<%= collection_select(:waste, :code, Waste.find_all_by_istoxic(false), :id, :code, :include_blank => '') %>
<%= f.check_box(:q_pripadnost) %>
<%= f.text_field(:amount) %>
<%= select_tag('nacinpakovanja',options_for_select([['Drveno bure', 'Drveno bure'], ['Kanister', 'Kanister'], ['Sanduk', 'Sanduk'], ['Kese', 'Kese'], ['Posude pod pritiskom', 'Posude pod pritiskom'], ['Kompozitno pakovanje', 'Kompozitno pakovanje'], ['Rasuto', 'Rasuto'], ['Ostalo', 'Ostalo']])) %>
<%= f.text_field(:ispitivanjebroj) %>
<%= f.text_field(:datumispitivanja) %>
<% end %>
```

and this in controller "report_main":

```
def exporttoxiccreate
    @report = ReportMain.new
    @reportexport = ReportExport.new
    @reportparam = params[:report_main]

    @report.waste_id = @reportparam.waste.code
    @report.warehouse_id = 1
    @report.user_id = 1
    @report.company_id = 1
    @report.amount = @reportparam.amount
    @report.isimport = false
    @report.isfinished = false

    if @report.save
      @reportexport.report_main_id = @report.id
    else
      redirect_to(:action => 'exporttoxicnew')
    end

    @reportexport.vrstaotpada = @reportparam.vrstaotpada
    @reportexport.nacinpakovanja = @reportparam.nacinpakovanja
    @reportexport.ispitivanjebroj = @reportparam.ispitivanjebroj
    @reportexport.datumispitivanja = @reportparam.datumispitivanja
    @reportexport.q_pripadnost = @reportparam.q_pripadnost

    if @reportexport.save
      redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @reportexport.id)
    else
      redirect_to(:action => 'exporttoxicnew')
    end
  end
```

And when I submit the form I got strange error:

> undefined method `belogns_to' for

Why I need belongs_to method? What goes there?

Comment: Looks like you spelled `belogns_to` wrong?

Comment: Is that error message a copy-and-paste from the error page? If so, it looks like there may be a typo somewhere in your code, since `belogns_to` has the `n` and the `g` the wrong way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to create an active record assocation of `belongs_to` but mispelled it to `belogns_to`. So go check your model.